# canvg fails on svg with xmlns

Tags: javascript, svg, canvg

I am using **canvg** to render the following svg to the canvas however it fails. I am not sure why

```
<svg class="circularReferenceSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <marker xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="triangle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="0" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="4" orient="auto">
                <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" fill="#000000"></path>
            </marker>
        </svg>
```

My guess is that it has to do something with **xmlns**. I could not find on the canvg webpage anything about it. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the screenshot of where the canvg seems to fail
[Here point and angle is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGMvd.png)

Comment: That SVG does not contain any elements that will display. i.e. it is blank. So if you render it on canvas it will be blank there too.

Comment: By 'fails' I mean that canvg throws an error. Even if the svg markup does not draw anything, still it should be able to parse it, however it does not

Comment: Throws what error, precisely?

Comment: @RobertLongson I have updated the question with the screenshot

Answer (score -1):

you need to wrap marker tag with defs tag.